# Как забиндить свой контрол на изменение заднего фона?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

Есть контрол, типа кнопки переключателя влево-вправо. 
Я хочу сделать так что бы при переключателю вправо изменялся цвет заднего фона.
(тоже самое что с NightMode - on/off)

Знаю только как можно менять при готовых объектов элементов VS, такой как ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding Path = Gender, Mode = TwoWay}" SelectedValuePath="Content">
                <ComboBoxItem Content="male"></ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="female"></ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

А как мне сделать с toggle-кнопкой:

```
<Grid>
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle x:Name="ToggleSwitch" Width="75" Height="30" Style="{StaticResource BaseButton}"          >
            </Rectangle>
            <Label     x:Name="SwitchLables"                          Style="{StaticResource SwitchLabel}" 
                       Canvas.Left="25" Canvas.Top="3"                                                           >SWITCH</Label>
            <Ellipse   x:Name="CircleShadow" Width="30" Height="30"  Fill="{StaticResource CircleBehind}"
                       Opacity="0.7"
                       MouseMove="CircleKnob_MouseMove"
                       ></Ellipse>
            <Ellipse   x:Name="CircleKnob" Width="24" Height="24"  Style="{StaticResource EllipseEffect}"
                       Fill="{StaticResource Circle}"

                       MouseDown="CircleKnob_MouseDown"
                       MouseMove="CircleKnob_MouseMove"
                       MouseUp  ="CircleKnob_MouseUp" Canvas.Top="3" Canvas.Left="3"   >
                <Ellipse.BitmapEffect>
                    <DropShadowBitmapEffect Direction="270" ShadowDepth="7" Opacity="0.4" Softness="1"              ></DropShadowBitmapEffect>
                </Ellipse.BitmapEffect>
            </Ellipse>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
```

.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class ToggleButton : UserControl
    {
        public ToggleButton()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        bool Action = false;
        double InitPxls = 3;
        double FinitePxls = 48;
        double Movement;
        Point Point;


        private void CircleKnob_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Action = true;
            Point = Mouse.GetPosition(CircleKnob);
            Mouse.Capture(CircleKnob);
        }

        private void CircleKnob_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Action)
            {
                Movement = Canvas.GetLeft(CircleKnob) + Mouse.GetPosition(CircleKnob).X - Point.X;

                if (Movement > InitPxls && Movement < FinitePxls)
                {
                    Canvas.SetLeft(CircleKnob, Movement);
                    Canvas.SetLeft(CircleShadow, Movement - 4);
                }
            }
        }

        private void CircleKnob_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Action = false;
            Mouse.Capture(null);

            if (Movement < FinitePxls / 2)
            {
                Canvas.SetLeft(CircleKnob, InitPxls);
                Canvas.SetLeft(CircleShadow, InitPxls - 4);
            }
            else
            {
                Canvas.SetLeft(CircleKnob, FinitePxls);
                Canvas.SetLeft(CircleShadow, FinitePxls - 4);
            }
        }
    }
```

Я не могу понять, как написать фун-ю которая проверяет где рычаг кнопки, если он на 48пикселе - значит включен?

```
private bool ONxOFF() {
                bool TurnedON;

                if (Movement == FinitePxls){
                    return TurnedON = true;
                }
                else {
                    return TurnedON = false;
                }
            }
```

Уже давно как начал разбираться с паттерном, но стою на одном и том же месте с binding'ом
А как его потом и куда передать? В Model сделай булевое свойство?

Comment: Так есть же штатный контрол `ToggleButton`, просто замените ему шаблон

Comment: Вашу задачу можно решить без единой строчки кода, только на XAML. Включая анимацию и т.п. Рекомендую почитать про `ControlTempate`, `Style`, `Trigger`.